# How did the Dursleys give Harry presents?

Tags: harry-potter

Harry gets a few presents via owl from the Dursleys: In his first year-

> A second, very small parcel contained a note.
> "We received your message and enclose your Christmas present. From Uncle Vernon and Aunt Petunia." Taped to the note was a fifty-pence piece.

In his second year-

> She nibbled his ear in an affectionate sort of way, which was a far better present than the one that she had brought him, which turned out to be from the Dursleys. They had sent Harry a toothpick.

In his 4th year-

> the Dursleys', which consisted of a single tissue, an all-time low.

So how did the Dursleys send Harry those presents? We know they really hate owls and anything to do with magic:

> 'OWLS AGAIN! I WILL NOT HAVE ANY MORE OWLS IN MY HOUSE!'

> "I WARNED YOU! I WILL NOT TOLERATE MENTION OF YOUR ABNORMALITY UNDER THIS ROOF!"

> ...How touchy they were about anything even slightly out of the ordinary.

> "Normal for us," said Harry, and before his uncle could stop him, he added, "you know, owl post. That's what's normal for wizards. "Uncle Vernon looked as outraged as if Harry had just uttered a disgusting swearword.Shaking with anger, he shot a nervous look through the window, as though expecting to see some of the neighbors with their ears pressed against the glass. "How many times do I have to tell you not to mention that unnaturalness under my roof?"

It's hard for me to think that the Dursleys would go that far as sending a message throw wizard-owl just to have the satisfaction of Harry getting a tissue as a present. Any explanation?

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/121384/76048

Comment: Very related, possible dupe: [How did Hedwig know the Dursleys would have a Christmas present for Harry?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/121384/98028). Uses the same extracts, but the question isn't exactly from the same point of view (Hedwig's vs Dursleys')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do the Dursleys use owl mail service?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188487/do-the-dursleys-use-owl-mail-service)